# How to use equals == operator in if else condition in handlebar

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, if-statement, handlebars.js

```
  {{#each user.Addtasks}}

{{#if {{this._id}} == {{ID}} }}

Statement;

Statement;

{{/if}}

{{/each}}
```

Here `_id` and `ID` both are getting passed from route to the handlebar page and now I want to compare them. How do I compare the two using `==`?

Comment: Let me know how can I achieve that as the above statements are not giving the results.

Comment: See here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252817/handlebarsjs-check-if-a-string-is-equal-to-a-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252817/handlebarsjs-check-if-a-string-is-equal-to-a-value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handlebarsjs check if a string is equal to a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252817/handlebarsjs-check-if-a-string-is-equal-to-a-value)

Comment: But i want to compare two values fetched from the route handlebar page which is written in two double brackets {{ }}. The comparison values are: {{this._id}} and {{Id}}