# Conditional line in handlebars.js with sugar

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, syntactic-sugar

I am looking to get the following logic in Handlebars.js

- the following **line** should appear in the output if `foo` is [truthy](https://www.google.com/search?q=truthy+javascript)

  `xxx.yyy.zzz = {{foo}}`
- no line should appear if `foo` is [falsy](https://www.google.com/search?q=falsy+javascript)

How can I do it?

**UPDATE**:

- I know I can wrap the line into an `#if` condition, but it's too wordy, is there a more elegant way?

**UPDATE**:

- The question is rather:

  - Whether or not Handlebars can handle it without an `#if` wrap for a **single line**?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34252817/3397771

Comment: this is cumbersome

Comment: Cumbersome? If you want to render something conditionally then you will need to include the condition. I'm not sure what uncumbersome solution you had in mind.

Comment: truthy is the keyword, something like this: `xxx.yyy.zzz = {{if foo}}`

Comment: that said, i am looking for sugar

Comment: *Truthy* is precisely what [an `#if` helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if) covers. If the goal is to control the appearance of `xxx.yyy.zzz = ` as well as `{{foo}}`, the condition has to wrap the entire line.

Comment: yes, the status-quo requires a wrapper, i am looking to get past it for a single line, can handlebars do it?

Comment: If you're able to find this sugar, I don't think you'll find it very sweet.

Comment: Not precisely as you envisioned. A helper can't effect text outside of its braces. Though, a custom helper could probably be defined with a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to handle `{{put-if foo 'xxx.yyy.zzz = ' foo}}`. If you don't like repeating `foo`, perhaps give it placeholders: `{{put-if foo 'xxx.yyy.zzz = ?'}}`.