# JSReport & Handlebars IF value is int

Tags: handlebars.js, jsreport

Have been struggling with JSreport couple hours today making PDF report for my app. Now met the problem in if statement, where I need to compare index number to integer.

In Javascript I can compare like this `if (partKey === 6)`, but with handlebars this is not working and I'll tried these with no luck:

```
{{#each computer.parts as |part partKey|}}
      <div class="item">
        <span>{{ part.productName }}, {{ part.weight }}g</span><br></br>
        {{ #if (eq partKey 6) }}
          <div style="page-break-before: always"></div>
        {{ /if }}
      </div>
      {{/each}}
```

I just want to change page after six objects. Also tried these; `{{ #is partKey 6 }}`, `{{ #if_eq partKey 6 }}`, `{{ #equals partKey 6 }}`.

Any ideas which should work?

If i print partKey like this `{{ partKey }}` it prints nicely. When I try to use it in `if` it gives a parse errpr, says partKey is `Invalid`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handlebarsjs check if a string is equal to a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252817/handlebarsjs-check-if-a-string-is-equal-to-a-value)

Comment: @76484 No. I tried that also.